# How to modify xml file with jenkins

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Im new to Jenkins 
looking for a way to modify the data of the XML file before executing script with this XML file as parameter 
didn't find any directions in google , please assist

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin.